# LinkButton Gets Hidden on AutoPostBack of SelectAll/Header CheckBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, telerik-grid, autopostback

I have a `telerik:radgrid` which has a checkbox and a linkbutton for each row and a check box in the header - to select all the checkboxes of the rows.

I am adding some dynamic text to the linkbutton from code behind using `HtmlGenericControl`

Like

```
status.Controls.Add(html_controller);
```

Where `status` is my linkbutton

Now the problem is that whenever I click on the header check box a postback occurs and my linkbutton along with the html_controller gets hidden. What changes should I do to fix it?

Below are the Header Checkbox and LinkButton

**Header Check Box** -

`<asp:CheckBox id="headerChkbox" OnCheckedChanged="ToggleSelectedState" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>`

**LinkButton** -

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="status"  runat="server" CommandName="Status" CausesValidation="false" style="text-align:center;cursor:pointer;" OnClientClick="return VerifyComments(this);"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by using a `asp:Label`(with `runat='server'`) within my `asp:LinkButton` instead of adding a `HtmlGenericControl` from code behind and assigned the dynamic text to Text field of the asp:Label (`labelname.Text`="")

The issue was apparently because of the postback issue with the `LinkButton` which got solved when I made use of `asp:Label` with `runat='server'`.